# Proof that $\sum 2^{-n\alpha}$ for $\alpha \in (0,1)$ converges

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to prove that $\sum 2^{-n\alpha}$ for $\alpha \in (0,1)$ converges.

I guess this should be really easy, but I'm currently a bit puzzled because whether I apply the ratio or root test, I need $2^{-\alpha} \leq C$ for some $C<1$, right?

But $\sup_{\alpha\in(0,1)} 2^{-\alpha}=1$, so how can this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a geometric series with ratio $2^{-\alpha}<1$ so you can take the limit of the partial sums.

Comment: Ah, I didn't think about that. Thanks. But to finish this: Is the statement correct that the convergence is inconclusive by ratio/root test alone?

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$\sum 2^{-n\alpha}=\sum \left(\frac1{2^{\alpha}}\right)^n$$

which is a converging [**geometric series**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) since $\frac1{2^{\alpha}}<1$.

To prove the convergence we can also use as an alternative

- ratio test: $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{\left(\frac1{2^{\alpha}}\right)^{n+1}}{\left(\frac1{2^{\alpha}}\right)^n}=\frac1{2^{\alpha}}<1$
- root test: $\sqrt{a_n}=\sqrt[n]{\left(\frac1{2^{\alpha}}\right)^{n}}=\frac1{2^{\alpha}}<1$

Comment: I get it now. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Amarus Yes indeed they works fine even if as noticed we don't need in that case since we know the closed expression for the partial sum in that case. You are welcome! Bye